# PATCHING/ PUTTING generated properties in REST API

Tags: rest

I have been struggling to find information on **how a resource that contains generated values is modified**. Below is a real world example:

Let's say we have 2 endpoints:

**/categories** and **/products**.

A **category** is used to contain various parameters that define any **product** belonging to it. For example, based on a category a product expiration date might be calculated, or some other properties might or *might not* be attached to a product.

Let's say we create **a new product** by sending a POST request to **/products** and among other fields we include the **category ID** property. Based on the category set a server creates and stores a new product along with various properties generated (expiration date, delivery policies) etc.

**Now the problem arises when needing to modify (PATCH/ PUT) the mentioned product.**

How are generated values edited? We can for example change a delivery policy, but then the product will contain a field that doesn't match what its attached category describes. Likewise, it might be very handy to modify its generated expiration date, however yet again that can create confusion about why a category says it should expire in 3 days but the product is set to expire in 20 days.

Another solution would be to make all these properties read-only and only allow regenerating them by changing the category, just like at creation.

However that poses 2 problems:

1. The biggest one being that a different category might not contain the same policy layout. For example, one category might enable generating GPS coordinates to ease the delivery, the other category does not. If we change the category, what do we do with these **valuable** properties already present? Do we drop them for the sake of clarity?
2. Another issue is limited flexibility. There might be cases when a property needs to be changed but the category needs to remain the same.

I think these questions are met and answered in probably every single REST API development and probably I am just missing something very simple and obvious. Could you help me understand the right way of going about this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> I think these questions are met and answered in probably every single REST API development and probably I am just missing something very simple and obvious. Could you help me understand the right way of going about this?

You write code to ensure that all of the invariants hold for the server's copy of the resource.

That can mean either (a) inspecting the body of the request, and returning a client error if the body doesn't satisfy the constraints you need to maintain, or (b) changing your resource in a way that doesn't exactly match the request you've received.

In the second case, you need to have a little bit of care with the response metadata, so that you don't imply that the representation of the request has been adopted "as is".

The code you are writing here is part of the origin server's implementation, deliberately hidden by the HTTP facade you present.  The general purpose components in the middle don't care about those details; they just want you to use messaging semantics consistent with the HTTP (and related) specifications.